# Pause loop operation until user provides complete input

Tags: c++, loops

In the code below, I am attempting to gather data from the user. However, the program accepts one input, then proceeds to print the remaining prompts to the screen.

How do I get the program to pause so that it collects data at each prompt from the user?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){

char items [10];
float budget;
float prices [10];
int i;

for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    cout << "Enter item name: "<<endl;
    cin >> items[i];
    cout << "Enter item price: "<<endl;
    cin >> prices [i];

    }

}
```

Comment: Please start with: How to use std::string (and C-strings) ? (You may get a book)

Comment: `cin >> items[i]` - that doesn't read a string. it tries to read a single `char`, leaving everything else you typed in the input stream. the followup read for a `float` fails (unless by some miracle you typed a name like "a123.45"), putting the stream into a failed state and ignoring every operation you perform thereafter. And that, kids, is why we *check our IO operations for success or failure*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char items [10];
```

Since this is an array of characters,
`std::cin` will only accept one character from the input buffer per index you are trying to set.

Consider using `std::string items[10]`, or even `std::vector<std::string>>` instead.